# Making it so registered users can't add/edit taxonomy terms to nodes

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, users

Is there a way to add a permission so only admins can add/edit taxonomy terms on nodes? I tried http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access but I don't really want full module and while rebuilding my content permissions I got an error so that module might not even work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a module that does this: [Taxonomy Role](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_role)